# Echoing sitecore item name in an ASPX layout

Tags: asp.net, css, layout, sitecore

I've got what I'm sure is a very simple Sitecore question, however I'm not familiar with ASP.NET at all and would appreciate any help that can be given. Below is a snippet of the LayoutMain.aspx file which, unsurprisingly, is the main layout file for the majority of the pages of the website I run.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LayoutMain.aspx.cs" Inherits="Company.Website.Layouts.LayoutMain" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Company.Business"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <!-- LayoutMain -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title><sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="item" runat="server" /></title>
```

I would like to add an ID and a couple of class attributes to the `<html>` tag. This will give me fine grained styling control via CSS of the entire site without having to mess around in .aspx files!

I would like the ID attribute to be taken from the first child level from `Sitecore\Home` and the class attribute to include both the current item name and the current item template item name. This would result in something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="shop" class="big-boxes product">
```

Where the current item is `Sitecore\Home\shop\boxes\big-boxes` in the main CMS tree and has a template of `product`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could simply do that with this line:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="shop" class='<%# Sitecore.Context.Item.Name + Sitecore.Context.Item.Template.Name %>'>
```

I hope that helps.

edit:

Remember to add a `Databind();` to the `Page_Load` method to get the data bound.

You can use the same principle to make the id dynamic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, unfortunately this just results in: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="shop" class=''>` I would also like to have the id attribute dynamic too - is that possible?

Comment: Use `<%=` rather than `<%#` other wise you would need to `Page.DataBind()`. To get the ID, just follow the example Holger gave you... `<html class='<%# Sitecore.Context.Item.Name + Sitecore.Context.Item.Template.Name %>' id='<%# Sitecore.Context.Item.Name %>'>`

Comment: Yep, what Sean said.  You get no output here because <%# %> is a "data-binding expression" and you are not data-binding.  The <%= %> is the generic "inline expression."  Output must be a string.

Comment: The problem with using <%= %> and sitecore is that makes the preview fail. Rather add a DataBind() to the Page_Load. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I went with `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="<%= Sitecore.Context.Item.Template.Name %>" class="<%= Sitecore.Context.Item.Name %>">` in the end as I don't have access to the code behind and no one uses the Sitecore Preview mode anyway due to other issues. Thanks everyone ;)

I don't suppose anyone has a quick link to where I can find a list of all available things like `Sitecore.Context.Item.Template.Name`?

Comment: Well if you have access to sdn.sitecore.net then there is plenty of stuff there, this link being a simple overview of probably the most used: http://sdn5.sitecore.net/Developer/Common%20API%20Classes.aspx

otherwise I don't know... you could debug the site and do a quickview of the Sitecore.Context and Sitecore.Context.Item objects...

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID too you will need to walk back up the ancestors of the current item until you find an item which has a parent of Home, that will give you your Shop item.

Ideally you should do this in code-behind rather than inline in the ASPX. You say you're not familiar with ASP.NET, add a comment if you have trouble with this to see if someone can help further.

In your ASPX:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="Html" runat="server" >
```

Then in your code behind, i.e. in the LayoutMain.aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Html.ID = GetHtmlID();
    Html.Attributes["class"] = GetHtmlClass();
}

protected string GetHtmlID()
{
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;

    while ( currentItem.Parent != null && currentItem.Parent.Name != "Home" )
    {
        currentItem = currentItem.Parent;
    }

    return (currentItem.Parent.Name == "Home") ? currentItem.Name : String.Empty;            
}

protected string GetHtmlClass()
{
    return string.Format( "{0} {1}", Sitecore.Context.Item.Name, Sitecore.Context.Item.Template.Name );
}
```

The GetHtmlID method here will attempt to find an ancestor which has Home as the parent (e.g. Shop). If it can't then you will end up without an ID, or you could change that `String.Empty` to put in a default ID.

Note that this hardcodes the Home template name directly into your code, ideally it would be better to move this out into config or instead match against Parent.ID with the Sitecore ID of your Home Item which is unlikely to change. However I imagine it's going to be rare that you would be renaming your Home item anyway.

Comment: This looks excellent and completely like the _The Right Way™_ to do it, but until I can get access to the code behind, I'm going to have to settle with the first answer. Thank you!

Comment: If you really needed that ID set correctly, you could still put that code straight into the ASPX file. Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/InlineCodeVSCodeBehind.aspx) for more info on putting code straight into your ASPX file. It's not best-practice but it will do in a pinch.